# Erro compareTo Key

Tags: java, comparação

Salve pessoal, tô com o seguinte problema, estou implementando um código que me retorna a mediana de uma sequência, usando max-heap e min-heap. Antes mesmo de concluir o código o compilador me retornou um erro:

```
method compareTo in interface java.lang.Comparable<T> cannot be applied to gives type; required: Key found java.lang.Comparable reason actual argument java.lang.Comparable cannot be converted to Key by method invocation conversion
```

No caso tanto max-heap quanto min-heap me retornam um tipo Key (metodo left.max()). Também na atribuição `v = left.max();` o compilador tá chiando, dei uma caçada no erro, mas não encontrei, se poderem me ajudar agradeço.

```
package median;

public class MedianPQ <Key extends Comparable<Key>>{
  private MaxPq left;
  private MinPq right;

  public MedianPQ(int N, int M) {
    left = new MaxPq(N);
    right = new MinPq(M);
  }

  private boolean less( Key k) {
    return k.compareTo(left.max()) < 0;
  }

  public void insert(Key k) {
    Key v;
    if( left.isEmpty() && right.isEmpty()) v = k;
    else {
      if( less(k) && (left.size() <= right.size() + 1)) {
        left.insert(k);
        v = left.max();
      }

    }
  }
```

Exemplo da classe max-heap (a classe min-heap é essencialemente a mesma):

```
public class MaxPq <Key extends Comparable <Key>>{
  private Key[] pq;
  private int N = 0;

  public MaxPq(int maxN) {
    pq = (Key[]) new Comparable[maxN + 1];
  }

  public boolean isEmpty() {
    return N == 0;
  }

  public int size() {
    return N;
  }

  public void insert( Key v) {
    pq[++N] = v;
    swin(N);
  }

  private boolean less( int i, int j) {
    return pq[i].compareTo(pq[j]) < 0;
  }

  private void exch(int i, int j) {
    Key t = pq[i]; pq[i] = pq[j]; pq[j] = t;
  }

  public void swin( int k) {
    while ( k > 1 && less(k/2, k)) {
      exch(k/2, k);
      k = k/2;
    }
  }

  public void sink( int k) {
    while( 2*k <= N) {
      int j = 2*k;
      if( j < N && less(j, j+1)) j++;
      if( !less( k, j)) break;
      exch(k, j);
      k = j;
    }
  }

  public Key delMax() {
    Key max = pq[1];
    exch(1, N--);
    pq[N+1] = null;
    sink(1);
    return max;
  }

  public Key max () {
    return pq[1];
  }
}
```

Comment: Pelo que entendi ele está chiando que `left.max()` retorna um `Comparable`. Não conheço as classes que está usando mas creio que você poderia fazer um cast `(Key)left.max()` ou então fazer uma troca, fazer `return left.max().compareTo(k) < 0;` mas tudo isso são chutes baseados na sintaxe sem levar em conta a semântica, ou seja, sem levar em conta o significado disso no código.

Comment: Editei a pergunta incluindo max-heap